# Preserve originally passed query string parameter throughout the site

Tags: php, wordpress

On the landing page of a wordpress site, I have two buttons. A click on each button leads you the the same page, but I passed a query string parameter on each one to help me distinguish them (because I want to adjust color of header and footer and show/hide some buttons based on the parameter value). The problem is, when I click somewhere else on the page, I lose that query string parameter. Is there a way I can preserve that parameter through every page load on the site?

I tried the following in my functions.php

```
echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' ) );
```

But that had no effect. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cookie instead. Specifically, I would use jQuery Cookie:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You could set a data value on the button:

```
<button class="my_button" data="theme_one">
<button class="my_button" data="theme_two">
```

When a user clicks a button:

```
jQuery( ".my_button" ).click( function( event ) {
    var theme = jQuery( this ).data();
    jQuery.cookie( "theme", theme );
} );
```

Then, on the next page you can grab the cookie value and do whatever you want:

```
var theme = $.cookie( "theme" );
if( theme ) {
    alert( theme );
}
```

Check out the jQuery Cookie plugin documentation to learn how to set the cookie duration.
Using this method you can keep the data stored on the user's machine and not have to worry about passing it around in an ugly query string.

In the code example above, you may need to prevent the event and then send the browser to the set URL after the cookie is set. It really depends on what you are doing already.